# Making a heightmap DEM for use in putting together a relief

Tags: qgis, dem, shaded-relief

I'm new to GIS, and I'm just doing this as a hobby.

I've seen 3d relief maps like this one: https://i.redd.it/peq57uoa28c51.jpg and I wanted to try my hand at making my own. I used the topoView service from USGS, and was able to acquire a .tif file, but that's the furthest I got.

Does anyone know how to create a relief like the one in the picture above? It doesn't look like the original author has any tutorials or guides.

Comment: you will need a high resolution DEM to drape your tiff over it. hopefully your tiff is 300dpi if you want to print this out. see https://viewer.nationalmap.gov/basic/ and elevation coverages.

Comment: @Mapperz not trying to print it out, just want to make a digital model like the image above. to start with that, what exactly would I do to make a relief? found a few different results from the link you sent, but I'm not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you need two things:

1. A source of DEM data
2. An overlay to drape over it eg a topographic map source

The image below uses

1. DEM data from ELVIS (https://elevation.fsdf.org.au/ - search for Katoomba)
2. An overlay using topographic tiles from NSW Spatial Services (set up a new WMS/WMTS connection using
   https://maps.six.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/public/NSW_Topo_Map/MapServer)/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml
   [image: Hillshade map of Katoomba, NSW]

- Use the Raster Terrain Analysis -> Hillshade tool from the Processing Toolbox to create a Hillshade layer from the DEM layer
- Set the Hillshade layer above the Topographic overlay in the Layer Toolbox
- Under Layer Properties -> Symbology, set the Color Rendering: Blending Mode to Multiply

Comment: thanks, I did this. what do I need to do next to combine the two layers, export them, and render them?

Comment: Printing/exporting is a whole separate question! Simplest option is to use Project->Import/Export->Export Map to Image... (or PDF). More sophisticated is to use Project->New Print Layout... The latter will probably require some research.

Comment: sorry, I meant how can I make the street map blend with the heightmap? I want to get to the same result you did with your screenshot. then I can simply clip and export into blender.

Comment: See the 3 steps above -  1. you need a Hillshade layer. 2. The hillshade layer needs to be above the topo (street map), and 3. The Blending Mode of the Hillshade layer needs to be set to Multiply

Comment: thanks, that's done. now, how can I combine the two layers and crop the map?

Comment: See instructions on printing/exporting above...

Comment: yeah, I think I got it to work. thanks so much!